# Como escrever uma tabela temporária

Tags: sql, postgresql

Preciso escrever no sql uma tabela temporária para usar em uma subquery.
Já consigo de duas formas, mas que produzem efeitos desagradáveis.

Imagino que exista mais alguma forma de criar essa tabela temporária, mas não descobri ainda como fazer isso.

Forma 1:

```
select letra from (
   (select 'a' as letra)
   union
   (select 'b' as letra)
) as tabela_temporaria
```

Prós: não usa nenhuma function.

Contra: no exemplo que deixo tem apenas 2 linhas, mas ocasionalmente podem ter inumeras linhas e o sql fica gigante, porque para cada um preciso escrever `(select 'x' as  letra) union`

Forma 2:

```
select letra from 
    (select unnest(array['a', 'b']) as letra) as tabela_temporaria
```

Prós: o sql fica reduzido.

Contra: usa uma function oque torna o desempenho mais demorado.

Objetivo almejado: Imagino que exista alguma outra forma mais correta, sem uso de funções, algo como:

```
Select letra from ('a', 'b', 'c') as letra
```

Alguma ideia?

Comment: Pq não cria uma view então?

Comment: Para usar view eu teria antes de executar o meu sql fazer o create da view, depois usa-la, e depois fazer o drop view. ou tem alguma forma de usar view temporaria? somente para esse sql? pois a cada execução do sql as linhas podem mudar, por ex. em um momento podem ser 'a', 'b', 'c', outro momento podem ser outras 'd', 'e' ... , elas não são fixas, senão eu teria criado uma tabela.

Comment: pq não ter então uma tabela com todas as possibilidades e na hora da consulta só mexer no filtro? acho bem mais prático do que ter que criar uma tabela temporária e popular toda vez que for consultar

Comment: Eu chamei o alias de 'letra' mas podem ser palavras ou frases, ou seja, não seria necessariamente um conjunto apenas das 26 letras do alfabeto seria um conjunto infinito de possibilidades, se para cada sql eu precisa-se fazer um insert em uma tabela física, nos filtros dessa tabela conteria exatamente o mesmo que foi no insert, como: insert into tabela (letra) values ('frase possivel1'), ('frase possivel2'); e no sql seria: select letra from tabela where letra = 'frase possivel1' or letra = 'frase possivel2'

Comment: ou vc pode deletar tudo da tabela antes de inserir, aí não precisaria do filtro... mas mesmo assim se existem infinitas possibilidades não vejo problema algum em ter a tabela, até porque uma hora outra pode ser que duplique e vc pode utilizar uma situação que já existe na tabela sem precisar duplicar registro.. mas claro isso td depende do problema que vc está tentando resolver às vezes é melhor deixar que a aplicação resolva a questão no lugar da base de dados

Comment: A cláusula VALUES não atende? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-values.html

Comment: Entendi o problema. Mas preciso de um cenário mais amplo. Essa informação "LETRA" é algo que você já tem em alguma tabela no seu banco de dados?
Porque eu imagino esta não seria a informação verdadeira. A desvantagem disso que não dá muito para entender sua estrutura atual para poder te ajudar a resolver.

Comment: A expressão: `VALUES ('a', 'b', 'c') AS tab_temp(letra)` atenderá ao que você expôs.